# jquery validation plugin and check unique field?

Tags: php, cakephp, jquery, jquery-validate

I am currently using jQuery validation plugin with cakephp in my new project.

It's working perfectly untill I need to make unique check to email field through ajax to check with the database..

I didn't know how to make the plugin make a unique validation to email from db.

thanx

Answer (score 3):

I reckon you are refering to using an AJAX call (via the plugin) to check for unique email with the server, yea?

I would suggest using the [addMethod](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/addMethod) of the validation plugin to create a custom validation in which you can make an [AJAX](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax) call (which will be part of the jQuery core).

There's an SO post on this topic which you can explore:
[JQuery Validate Plugin - How to create a simple, custom rule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/241145/j)

Do note that you will have to implement the server-side script yourself.

Here's another article which should be useful (using jQuery and PHP):
[Check email already exist – Ajax – Jquery](http://beski.wordpress.com/2009/05/16/check-email-already-exist-ajax-jquery/)

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is simple

```
$.validator.addMethod("eventName", 
    function(value, element) {
            // condition returns true or false 
    }, "Error message to display");
});
```

Event name is called in the form

```
<input type="text" name="name" class="eventName" />
```

Refer this link if any more doubts

[jQuery Validate Plugin - How to create a simple custom rule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/241145/jquery-validate-plugin-how-to-create-a-simple-custom-rule)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check if the email is unique you can use remote rule.
It is from: http://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method

**Example: Makes the email field required, an email and does a remote request to check if the given address is already taken.**

```
$( "#myform" ).validate({
  rules: {
    email: {
    required: true,
    email: true,
    remote: "check-email.php"
   }
  }
});
```

**Example: Makes the email field required, an email and does a remote request to check if the given address is already taken. In addition, the http method is set to “post” and the username is sent alongside the email address.**

```
$( "#myform" ).validate({
  rules: {
   email: {
     required: true,
     email: true,
     remote: {
          url: "check-email.php",
          type: "post",
          data: {
             username: function() {
              return $( "#username" ).val();
              }
          }
     }
  }
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
  $.validator.addMethod("unique",
            function(value, element, params) {
                var isUnique = false;
                if(value == '')
                        return isUnique;

                id_send= '';
                if(params[1] !='')
                    id_send ='id='+params[1]+'&';

                $.ajax({
                    url: "path"+params[2],
                    type : 'GET',
                    async: false,
                    data: id_send+'field=' + params[0] + "&value=" + value,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    cache: true,
                    success: function(data){
                        isUnique = data;
                    }
                });

                return isUnique;

            },
            jQuery.validator.format("Value already in use")
    );
```

In the above code:

- path is the root path of your application;
- params[0] is the name of attribute to check unique;
- params[1] is the id of the object, if you want to check in edit too, so exclude himself;
- params[2] is the path to the php file that gonna check.

Resulting in something like:

```
 rules:
        {
            email: {
                required: true,
                unique:['email', $('#user_id').val(),'uniqueemail.php'],
                email: true
            },
```

The PHP uniqueemail.php, search for the **value** in field **email**, if return empty or the user with id equals **$('#user_id').val()** so return true, else return false.

Note that the **async** attribute is set **false**, this is a set back but is gonna do the job.