# jQuery Validation - get list of erroneous fields in invalidHandler

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, validation, jquery-validate

I'm using jQuery Validation on a page. During the call to the invalidHandler I would like to be able to access a list of all the form elements that failed validation.

This function is being passed as one of the options to the jQuery.validate() method...

```
invalidHandler: function (form) {
    var validator = $("#AddEditFinancialInstitutionForm").validate();
    validator.showErrors();
    console.log(validator);
}
```

I'm trying to find this information somewhere in the resulting validator object, but I can't seem to find it.  Is there another way I can access this information?

Thanks

Answer (score 36, accepted):

In the `invalidHandler`, you are passed two arguments, a `jQuery.Event` and the `validator` object.  You don't need to call validate within your invalidHandler to get the validate object.  Further, the validator object has a properties called `errorList` and `errorMap`, which contain the information you are looking for.

```
invalidHandler: function(e,validator) {
    //validator.errorList contains an array of objects, where each object has properties "element" and "message".  element is the actual HTML Input.
    for (var i=0;i<validator.errorList.length;i++){
        console.log(validator.errorList[i]);
    }

    //validator.errorMap is an object mapping input names -> error messages
    for (var i in validator.errorMap) {
      console.log(i, ":", validator.errorMap[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this also the right event to know which errors have been fixed? What does `validator.currentElements` contain?

Comment: You just saved me from having the insanity of searching through the minified content of the plugin file! I had a stray `min="0"` on a text input and this really helped me. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

If you are using the default error class and only find the invalid elements, use

```
 $(this).find("input.error") // inside invalidHandler
```

Comment: $(document).find("input.error") // On Chrome console

Answer (score 2):

use this for getting errored field's whole element and it's attributes.

```
  var formerrorList = $("#FORM_ID_HERE").data("validator").errorList;
        $.each(formerrorList, function (key, value) {
            console.log(formerrorList[key].element.id);
        });
```