# How to see jQuery validation list of elements with errors

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, validation, jquery-validate

Sometimes, the form won't submit because jQuery has some invalid elements that will not show up in an error message.

How can we see these errors in order to debug more easily ?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

```
var validator = $("form").validate()
validator.errorList
```

will show the array of errors that are holding back the form from submiting.

Comment: console.log(validator); opens up new horizons for me :)

Comment: console.dir(foo) is nice, too (depending on your browser).

Comment: 2017 and this saved me so much time!

Comment: 2021 and this saved me lots of time also. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

This works for me to get a list of validation errors (ids of error inputs and associated error message):

```
    if ($('#form').valid()) {

        console.log('FORM VALID');

    } else {

        console.log('FORM INVALID');

        var validator = $('#form').validate();

        $.each(validator.errorMap, function (index, value) {

            console.log('Id: ' + index + ' Message: ' + value);

        });

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 var val = $("#form".validate());
 console.log("error list", val);
```

for those who dont get errorList working that way, just go to console and click on the errorList

Answer (score 0):

errorList only seems to work exactly right for me after running a call with valid() in it.

```
var validator = jQuery('#form1').validate();
if(jQuery('#form1').valid()){
    var submitErrorsList = new Object();
    for (var i=0;i<validator.errorList.length;i++){
        submitErrorsList[validator.errorList[i].element.name] = validator.errorList[i].message;
    }
}
console.log("Submit Errors", submitErrorsList);
```

Comment: Should this be if(!jQuery('#form1').valid()){

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative for getting client-side validation errors is [reportValidity()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reportValidity).

EXAMPLE:

```
form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
    if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
        form.reportValidity();
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        ...
```