# unobtrusive validation with custom validator that requires ajax post

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I'm using ASP.NET MVC with unobtrusive validation. I need to add a new custom validation attribute with client-side validation, which is fine (I've already got some of those defined). The problem is that in the client side validation, I need to make an ajax call to check if the input is valid.

In MVC, you add client-side validators with addMethod:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("customValidation", function(){...})
```

But the function you define needs to return a boolean, and doing an ajax post is aysnc, which breaks that.

According to [jQuery validator and a custom rule that uses AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2628413/jquery-validator-and-a-custom-rule-that-uses-ajax) there are 2 options - either use `async:false` in the ajax call or add a `remote` to the validate method. BUT, `async:false` is depcrated and I can't use `remote` because I'm using unobtrusive validation.

Has anyone got any better solutions to this?

Comment: Can you post the javascript validation method, or at least its logic ?

Answer (score 0):

Data annotations contain a `Remote` attribute that plugs into jquery remote validation automatically.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.remoteattribute(v=vs.98).aspx