# Ajax submit certain field

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm new to Jquery ajax, and I'm trying to submit certain field only for checking instead of submitting the whole form. Here I have made a function for checking the username whether is it available, and it works fine, but I doesn't want it to submit the whole form when doing the checking.

Here is my script:

```
<form id="userCheck">
<input type="text" class="register_field" name="fr_username" id="fr_username" />
<input type="text" class="register_field" name="fr_password" id="fr_password" />
<input type="text" class="register_field" name="fr_password1" id="fr_password1" />
</form>

<script>
$.validator.addMethod("duplicateCheck", function(value, element) {
            $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '../a/checkDuplicate',
        data: $("#userCheck").serialize(),
        dataType: 'json'
    }).success(function(data){
        if(data.status == '1'){
            console.log('Available!');
        }
        else {
            console.log('not available');
            $('#fr_dupChkU_msg').html('');
        }
    });
        });
</script>
```

Comment: Just put the user name field data into your ajax call data field.

Comment: @Jurik I tried, but it will submit as empty value.

Comment: Your code shows ... well it should end in an javascript error.

Comment: @Jurik Perhaps an example on how to put field data?

Comment: Maybe this is related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2628413/jquery-validator-and-a-custom-rule-that-uses-ajax

Answer (score 1):

In short, that is how you get a value of an input field with jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var username = $('#fr_username').val();

  $.validator.addMethod('duplicateCheck', function(value, element) {
            $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '../a/checkDuplicate',
        data: {username: username},
    }).success(function(data){
        if(data.status == '1'){
            console.log('Available!');
        }
        else {
            console.log('not available');
            $('#fr_dupChkU_msg').html('');
        }
    });
        });
</script>
```

Comment: I followed your instruction, sadly to say as what I expected. Empty submission. http://prntscr.com/bfs1be

Comment: What do you mean with 'empty submission'? Could you share us your network traffic? What data was sent to your server?

Comment: you can refer the screenshot I have attached on my previous comment

Comment: Did you use my example? Because I deleted `data-type`.

Comment: yeah I did, but still the same. I felt pretty unsafe to submit a form with empty value. Probably caused by conflicts with my framework?

Comment: What happens when you use `var username = $('#fr_username').val();` in your console - is there a value?

Comment: empty too... That is the funny thing, however, if I put outside of the function,the username variable contains the value

Comment: still nope :( Probably it needs the form name

Comment: I added this code seems to work....
`var username = $('#userCheck').find('input[name="fr_username"]').val();`
Anyway thanks!