# how to validate alphanumeric numeric and higlight the fields using jquery

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-validate

I am looking for validation using jquery on a simple form and I want to know how I can check for alphanumeric or numeric.  Then I want to highlight the error text field using rules.  This code is working great is entered in the fields can anyone help on adding this functionality to my code?

here is the code i have used

```
$("#frmstudent").validate({
      rules:{
          txt_name :{ required:true, minlength : 3 },  

          txt_fname:{ required:true, minlength : 3  },

          txt_class:{ required:true, minlength: 2 },

          txt_city:{ required:true, minlength : 3},

          txt_contact:{ required:true, minlength : 5 },

          txt_email:{ required:true, email:true, minlength : 8},

          txt_address:{ required:true , minlength : 10}

      },
      messages:{

          txt_name:{required:"<i>Please enter ur full name</i>",
                    minlength:"<i>please enter at least 3 characters</i>"},

          txt_fname:{required:"<i>Please enter the fathers name in required field</i>",
                    minlength:"<i>please enter at least 3 characters</i>"},

          txt_class:{required:"<i>Please enter the your class name</i>",
                    minlength:"<i>please enter at least 2 characters</i>"},

          txt_city:{required:"<i>Please enter your city name</i>",
                    minlength:"<i>please enter at least 3 characters</i>"},

          txt_contact:{required:"<i>Please enter your contact details</i>",
                    minlength:"<i>please enter at least 5 characters</i>"},

          txt_email:{required:"<i>Please enter your valid email address</i>",
                    minlength:"<i>please enter at least 8 characters</i>"},

          txt_address:{required:"<i>Please enter your address</i>",
                    minlength:"<i>please enter at least 10 characters</i>"}


      }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add a custom rule to validate the alphanumeric characters. For this create a custom rule and validate using some regular expression in the custom created method. Check the SO post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/241145/jquery-validate-plugin-how-to-create-a-simple-custom-rule)

Comment: but isnt there any simple way like required minlength for numeric and alpahnumeric characters in rules for jquery

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6384351/validate-age-before-registering-a-user-to-check-if-hes-over-a-certain-age-using-m