# jquery validation - waiting for remote check to complete

Tags: validation, jquery

When I call `$("form").valid()` I have a remote validation check hooked up (which all works well) however if all other fields are valid the form passes validation because the remote check hasn't return a response "quick enough".

Is there a way to either force jquery validation to wait for any remote checks to be completed or hook into the complete event of the remote check call?

I am currently using the remote validator built into the jQuery validation framework http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/remote

Comment: SO is there no way to achieve automatically via the jquery validation framework?

Answer (score 4):

one way is to introduce a variable that will be set to true when the remote call comes back

```
var remote_complete = false;

$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  success: function(){
    remote_complete = true;
  }
});

while (remote_complete == false)
  {
  // loop until  remote_complete = true;
  }
```

Another way is to validate your form after remote validation completes

```
 $.ajax({
      url: "test.html",
      success: function(){
        validate_form();
      }
    });
```

Comment: Be careful of the while loop - it could cause the browser to become unresponsive.

Comment: I would prefer the latter. If you really want to take the former approach, at least use `setInterval`.

Comment: while without setinterval - bad idea

Comment: @Andrew I looked up setInterval and I don't get how it applies here.  Please post what you were thinking.

Comment: I added 2 functions: validateForm and validateField in this 2 two functions I set flags, if requests are penging, and in stopRequest I triger events form-valid or field-valid (depend on flags)

Answer (score 2):

you can add a **custom rule** and in that custom rule you can make the ajax call.

Please check the SO post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/241145/jquery-validate-plugin-how-to-create-a-simple-custom-rule) for creating custom rules.

In that function make the ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you've setup all your rules correctly, then this shouldn't be a problem. See this [demo](http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/milk/) where email is being validated remotely and the validation doesn't pass until the check comes back.

Can you post a jsfiddle that highlights your problem?

Answer (score 0):

http://gloryplus.com/index.php?route=product/product&path=82&product_id=173

```
rules: {
      name: {
        minlength: 2,
        required: true
      },
      email: {
        required: true,
        email: true
      },
      subject: {
        minlength: 2,
        required: true
      },
      message: {
        minlength: 2,
        required: true
      }
    },
    highlight: function(label) {
        $(label).closest('.control-group').addClass('error');
    },
    success: function(label) {
        label
            .text('OK!').addClass('valid')
            .closest('.control-group').addClass('success');
    }
```