# jQuery Validate's remote method inside a jQuery UI Dialog only works once

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-validate, jquery-ui-dialog

I need to use the 'remote' method to check the availability of a company name before proceeding to insert the said company

I'm currently using jquery UI Dialog for entry of the  company's data , since I need to do it on the same page where I then list all the companies

Currently I have it more or less working but not as expected, as the remote method works only the first time, the next time I try to open the dialog and try entering a name that already exists, the 'remote' method simply doesn't work anymore and I don't know what this is due to.

**Edit** : I gonna try and see if I can explain it

Let's say I have 2 registered companies : **company1** and **company2**

1. The first time the page is loaded I open the dialog trying to re-enter let's say: **'company2'**, the 'remote' method works correctly(The
   WebMethod is only called  when  **'txtName'** loses focus and from there on, each time the content is changed) I suppose that is the
   normal behaviour, isn't it?
2. If I change the text and, let's say, I enter **'company20'** instead, which
   doesn't exist among the registered companies,  this time the company
   is registered correctly.
3. The problem in question occurs when trying again to re-enter the previous value (**company20**) , in this case the WebMethod is no longer
   called , allowing you to register **'company20'** AGAIN, as if
   did not exist, which is not  true.It is as if **'company20'** were kept
   as a valid value, right from the first time the dialog was opened,
   but if I enter another value, that really exists such as **company1** or
   **company2**, the 'remote' method works correctly again.

I do not know if I have explained it well , since it is rather confusing, even for me, but I hope you have understood me and that you can help me.

Here's all the **javascript** I use :

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">

    <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {     

            var dialogFormValidator= $("#form2").validate({
                 rules: {
                   txtName: {
                      required: true,
                      remote: function(){
                        var result={
                            type: "POST", 
                            url: "RemoteMethod.aspx/IsUnique",
                            data: "{'name': '" + $('#txtName').val() + "'}" ,
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",  
                            dataType: "json",                              
                            dataFilter: function(data) { 
                                  var x = (JSON.parse(data)).d;
                                  return JSON.stringify(x); 
                            }  

                        }
                        return result;
                      }
                  },
                  txtAddress: {
                      required: true
                  }
               },
               messages :{
                 txtName : {       
                    remote: " That name is already taken,please enter a different one."
                 }               

               }

            });
            $("#dialog-form").dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                width: 350,
                height: 290,
                modal: true,
                beforeClose: function(event, ui) { 
                    $("#txtName").val("");
                    $("#txtAddress").val("");   
                    dialogFormValidator.resetForm();                    

                },
                buttons:
                {
                    "Add": function() {

                        var valid = dialogFormValidator.form(); 
                        if (valid) {
                            var name = $("#txtName").val();
                            var address = $("#txtAddress").val();


                            var params = new Object();
                            params.name = name;
                            params.address = address;
                            params = JSON.stringify(params);

                            $.ajax({
                                type: 'POST',
                                url: 'RemoteMethod.aspx/AddNewItem',
                                data: params,
                                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                dataType: "json",
                                success: function(msg) {
                                    if (msg.d) {

                                        <%=ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(UpdatePanel1,"") %>;
                                        $("#dialog-form").dialog("close");

                                    }
                                },
                                error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                                    alert(textStatus + ": " + XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
                                }
                            });
                         } 


                        },
                        "Cancel": function() {                           
                            $(this).dialog("close");
                        }
                    }
            });

            $("#add").click(function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $("#dialog-form").dialog("open");
            });
        });

    </script>    
</asp:Content>
```

As you can see ,  once all the validations are met, I immediately refresh the UpdatePanel's content(a gridview where I show all the existing companies ) via javascript.( I used an UpdatePanel just for the sake of simplicity)

And here's also the WebMehod used to check the availability of a company name :

```
 <WebMethod()> _
    Public Shared Function IsUnique(ByVal name As String) As Boolean
        Dim count As Integer = 0
        Using cn As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.Conexion.ToString())
            Dim sql As String = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Companies WHERE Name=@Name"
            cn.Open()
            Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(sql, cn)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", name)
            count = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
            cn.Close()
        End Using
        If count Then
            Return False
        Else
            Return True
        End If

    End Function
```

**Edit : ASP.net markup :**

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <a href="#" id="add">Add New</a>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:GridView ID="gvSucursales" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                    DataKeyNames="Id">                  
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id">
                            <ItemStyle Width="50px" />
                        </asp:BoundField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Nombre" HeaderText="Name">
                            <ItemStyle Width="200px" />
                        </asp:BoundField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Direccion" HeaderText="Address">
                            <ItemStyle Width="300px" />
                        </asp:BoundField>
                    </Columns>                  
                </asp:GridView>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder2" runat="server">
    <div id="dialog-form" title="Add new Company">
        <p>
            All the fields are required.</p>
        <form id="form2">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="txtName" id="lblName">
                        Name</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="txtName" id="txtName" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="txtAddress" id="lblAddress">
                        Address</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="txtAddress" id="txtAddress" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </form>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Any ideas on how to solve this will be really appreciated

Comment: Is your #form2 element also in the updatepanel ?

Comment: @DidierG.- No, it isn't. The #form2  is in a ContentPlaceHolder, I've added that part so that you can get a better idea

Comment: I quickly checked but had not real trouble with same implementation (except the database call checking the name). What is exactly "not working anymore" ? Is the remote val. not called anymore ? Do you get an error ?

Comment: @DidierG. - I've tried to describe the problem in detail, please take a look at the original question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I suspected the plugin seems to cache the value and gloogling a little bit I found I can invalidate the cache manually using `removeData("previousValue")` and that's exactly what I did :

```
$("#txtName").change(function () {
    $("#txtName").removeData("previousValue");
});
```

and guess what...? **It works!**

Comment: @DidierG. Thanks :D I really appreciate what you've been doing for me the past few days

Answer (score 1):

First I've got one question: is your `AddNewItem` page method gets hit ?

I have created myself a little project based on your code.
For me the call to `IsUnique` was all the time ok.
I had troubles when calling the `AddNewItem` page method though, always got an `Internal 500 Error` returned.

The way you pass your `params` object to the `AddNewItem` method is not correct. Your code will generate a json string like this:

```
var params = new Object();
params.name = name;
params.address = address;
params = JSON.stringify(params);

// params => '{"name": "xxx", "address": "ndndnd"}'
```

But asp.net expects this: `'{"params": {"name": "xxx", "address": "ndndnd"}}'` (assuming the parameter for AddNewItem is called "params".

```
var oParams = new Object();
oParams.name = name;
oParams.address = address;

var oData = { 'params' : oParams };

$.ajax({
   ...
   data: JSON.stringify(oData),
   ...
});
```

After changing that, my project works as expected, I can add new items and the IsUnique takes into consideration added items.

Hope this is the solution to your problem...
Tell if it does not suit your needs

---

**Using remote validation rule and .form()**

There is also a possible flaw in your "Add" button handler. You are doing this:

```
 var valid = dialogFormValidator.form(); 
 if (valid) {
```

The problem is that remote rule takes *some time* to execute and until it has completely executed, the field will be considered valid.

This meabns that `if (valid)` is `true` until the remote rule has ended executing, and if it actually invalidates the field, it'll be too late.

I found an article about this problem: [https://stackoverflow.com/...jquery-validation-waiting-for-remote-check-to-complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6467864/jquery-validation-waiting-for-remote-check-to-complete)

I'm not really happy with while() solution proposed in the article but it can give you ideas.

Comment: I didn't have any problem with the `AddNewItem` method since my WebMethod **expected** two parameters:'name' and 'address', but I must admit that your suggestion is way more practical and was exactly the way I wanted to pass my parameters(**Once more, thank you**) but since I had absolutely no idea how to do it, I ended up passing the parameters one by one

Comment: Now, regarding the problem with `remote` method , I tried using the `remote_complete` variable and putting the `return result;` inside the `while`,but the problem remains I also noticed that the issue seems to get solved by its own if I refresh the page.. the problem is , that's exactly what I'm trying to avoid