# using jquery validation engine

Tags: jquery, jquery-validation-engine

My question i have the above form in my page. i want to validate the form using jquery validation engine.Can you pls tell me how to validate it and what r the files to include. now, i have included the jquery validation engine in my head. i just want to know how to trigger the validation engine and show the error message onblur of the text fields.. many thanks in advance.please find my code below:

```
<script src="../js/jquery-1.6.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="scripts/jquery.validationEngine-en.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="scripts/jquery.validationEngine.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        // binds form submission and fields to the validation engine
        $('#myForm').validationEngine('validate');
    });


</script>
<form class="container" id="myForm" method="post" action="">
    <div>
        <span>Field is required : </span>
        <label for="Firstname">Firstname</label>
        <input type="text" class="validate[required] text-input" id="name" name="Firstname"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span>Field is required : </span>
        <label for="name">middlename</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="middlename" class="validate[required] text-input"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span>Field is required : </span>
        <label for="name">lastname</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="lastname" class="validate[required] text-input"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Hi, My question i have the above form in my page. i want to validate the form using jauery validation engine.Can you pls tell me how to validate it and what r the files to include. now, i have included the jquery validation engine in my head. i just want to know how to trigger the validation engine and show the error message onblur of the text fields.. many thanks in advance

Comment: Probably related to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8628873/jquery-validation-engine). It got downvotes for *a reason*, you know.

Comment: Do *not* ask the same question repeatedly.

Answer (score 10):

Change your jquery code to this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   jQuery(document).ready(function(){
       // binds form submission and fields to the validation engine
       $('#myForm').validationEngine();
   });

</script>
```

Then add some classes to your form field , for example :

it is an input text and it is required :

```
<input type='text' class="validate[required] text-input">
```

or this one is an input text for just emails :

```
<input type='text' class="validate[required,custom[email]] text-input">
```

put a button and on its Click event call a javascript function like this :

```
function myValidation()
{

    if ($('#myForm').validationEngine('validate'))   
    { 
        //do somthing here beacause your form is valid
    }
}
```

For more help comment me

Answer (score 7):

Refer this **[jQuery.validationEngine](https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine)** to know how to use Validation Engine.

For writing Custom rule, refer this existing question **[jQuery Validate Plugin - How to create a simple custom rule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/241145/jquery-validate-plugin-how-to-create-a-simple-custom-rule)**

Comment: Thanks siva.. that article was helpful :)

Answer (score 3):

all thing go right and you do that correct ,you can just call this method to validate all the field of your form

```
$('#myForm').validationEngine('validate');
```

this will return true if all field of your form validate right , else return false

Answer (score 1):

Follow this:

Download jquery validation engine plugin from [here.](https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine) And extract it.

Inside the folder you can find these two files.

```
jquery.validationEngine-en.js 
jquery.validationEngine.js
```

Copy & Paste in assets->scripts-> of your working project.

Then change the `src` path like below.

```
<script src="assets/scripts/jquery.validationEngine-en.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

<script src="assets/scripts/jquery.validationEngine.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

In Your Coding do the following:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#id of ur form").validationEngine();
    });
</script>
```