# Validation on conditional MVC Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am working on MVC razor. I have to do validation depend on condition. 
Condition is below mentioned

1. We have country dropdown which is having Country USA and UK. when i 
   select USA from Drop down then I do not want any validation on city 
   and zip text box.

   2.When I select US from drop down then i want validation on city and zip text box.

How to implement this scenario on mvc razor.

Comment: [What have you tried ?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: i know only data annontaion validation on mvc razor.but i don't know how to implement this secnario.if you know about mentioned scenario,please tell me how to do code for this

Comment: i do not go with jquery.can we do by model

Comment: **I** think, You can only do this by `jquery/js` not other way for this..

Comment: are you sure?i think other way may be available.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using jQuery validation.

```
if(...)
    $('#target').rules('add', { ... });
else
    $('#target').rules('remove');
```

Or you can add custom method:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod(...);
```

See: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/addMethod

Answer (score 0):

For the client side you have to do the validation yourself by creating custom validation method. You can see an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/241145/jquery-validate-plugin-how-to-create-a-simple-custom-rule).

At the server-side I may suggest you to go for implementing `IModelValidatable` in the model class. You can get more information about this in this blog [post](http://prideparrot.com/blog/archive/2012/4/model_validation_in_asp_net_mvc). I also suggest you may create an `Address` model that wraps up the properties and validation so you don't need to repeat the validation in many models.