# Add JS function in Jquery to check username available or not live

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

I want to ask the question about JS function, now I want the function is checking username
Here it's my JS code :

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("noSpace", function(value, element) { 
    return value.indexOf(" ") < 0 && value != ""; 
    });

    $().ready(function()
    {
        $("#signupForm").validate(
        {
            rules:
            {
                full_name: "required",
                username: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 2,
                    noSpace: true,
                },
                password: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 5
                },
                email: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                },
            },
            messages:
            {
                full_name: "Please enter your full name",
                username:
                {
                    required: "Please enter a username",
                    minlength: "Your username must consist of at least 2 characters",
                    noSpace: "No space allowed",
                },

                password:
                {
                    required: "Please provide a password",
                    minlength: "Your password must be at least 5 characters long"
                },

                email: "Please enter a valid email address"
            }
        });
    });
```

So how can I add the function to checking available username and show it in below the input text username (if available or not), If available user can continue the submit the form. If not, user can't continue submit the form.

To check the username I using PHP language with Mysql Database.

Any idea ?

Comment: Which server side language are you using? You need server side support to check if username is available or not & call that page through AJAX.

Comment: @KapilSharma I using PHP language. Have an example ?

Comment: May be this post can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/241145/jquery-validate-plugin-how-to-create-a-simple-custom-rule

Comment: @NagaBotak with php are u using any framework , what is the database you are using MYsql ? what is the structure of your user table ?

Comment: http://www.99points.info/2010/06/live-availability-checking-with-ajax-and-jquery/

Comment: So how can I combine with your suggestion code in my JS function ?

Comment: Do you need to send requst to server in order to get availbility for user?

Comment: @AntonBaksheiev Yes that's right. Can you give me an example with combine my JS function ?

Answer (score 0):

try use this example, pay attantion how checkAvailability is used here

```
$(document).ready(function() {
jQuery.validator.addMethod("checkAvailability",function(value,element){
 var x= $.ajax({
    /*Setting of request*/
 }).responseText;

 if($("message", x).text()=="true") return true;
 else return false;
},"Sorry, this user name is not available");

$("#loginForm").validate({
    rules:  {
        username: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 4,
            checkAvailability: true
        },
    },

    submitHandler: function(form){send()}
});
});
```

Comment: it depends on what language you uses, so if you use PHP you should write page that get JSON result. This rezult should be like {"message":true} or {"message":false} (if we talk about exmaple over).

Comment: var x= $.ajax({
   /*settings*/
 }).responseText;
 if($("message", x).text()=="true") return true;
 else return false;  here you should write logic of getting value of valibility. There are several way so you can chose one that well for you