# validate the format of a field depending on other field

Tags: jquery, validation

would like to check if the driver license is exactly 6 numbers if the option field above is state DE
jsfiddle code below

### http://jsfiddle.net/THKez/1/

```
<form name="clientdetails_form" id="clientdetails_form" method="POST" action="xxxx.php">  

<p>
<label for="state">State</label>
<select type="text" name="state" >
<option value="NY">NY</option>
<option value="DE">DE</option></select>
</p>

<p>
<label for="LicenseN"><em>*</em>License #</label>
<input id="ClientLicensenNum"  name="ClientLicensenNum" type="text" value="" >
</p>    

    <input type="submit" value="submit"  >    

</form>
```

thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/241145/jquery-validate-plugin-how-to-create-a-simple-custom-rule

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a custom method to handle DE licenses with 6 characters:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("DELicense", function(value, element) {
    if (this.optional(element)) {
        return true;
    }

    if ($('select[name="state"] option:selected').val() == 'DE') {
        return $(element).val().match(/^\d{6}$/);
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}, "DE Licenses must be 6 numbers");
```

When you call validate, specify that this custom type must be used when your select is set to DE:

```
$("#clientdetails_form").validate({
    rules: {
        ClientLicensenNum: {
            DELicense: true,
            required: true
        }
    }
});​
```

See it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/THKez/3/

**EDITTED** to make it a bit more complicated - turns out custom rules can't use `dependency-expressions` the way [required](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/required#dependency-expression) can.

Comment: Except that the function is handling not only DE licenses it does trigger even with NY, which is not supposed to be. is there a way to use if statement ? but really using Regex is very nice in here thanks

Comment: Good point - I changed it back to an older version I had made

Comment: thanks again, just one last tweak, how can we show the text error only when user TAB to another field or the selected field looses focus or the user submits the form as it is in the default behavior for this module. not a big deal but just to make it look perfect.

Comment: That is weird - It really shouldn't be doing anything until you submit the first time...

Answer (score 0):

On change of the drop down, if the state is DE and the length is 6, do something. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/djUAY/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select').change(function() {
        var state = $(this).val();
        var license = $('#ClientLicensenNum').val();
        if (state == "DE" && license.length == 6) {
            console.log('Do something');
        }
    });
});​
```