# Validate 4th letter of a word using jqueryvalidation

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using http://jqueryvalidation.org/. And I want to add a rule to validate the field from the value entered by users on fourth letter.

Like if value is = ABCPUJJE

and we set rule that fourth letter = P

then the rule will check fourth value and display message "Right value entered"  else "Please Enter correct value"

Comment: You should have made an honest attempt at this yourself before asking for help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery Validate Plugin - How to create a simple, custom rule?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/241145/jquery-validate-plugin-how-to-create-a-simple-custom-rule)

Comment: I am a designer and did know nuch abou jquery so i asked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Defining custom method**

```
function myTextOnlyValidation(value, element){

   var fourthChar = value.charAt(3);

   if (fourthChar === 'P') {
     return true;
   } else {
     return false;
   }
}
```

**Add custom method to jquery validator**

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("validateChar", myTextOnlyValidation, "Custom Message");
```

**Adding validation to the element**

```
$('#TestForm').validate({
  rules : {
     txtboxElement: { validateChar: true }
  }
});
```