# How to get true or false by jQuery Validation Plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using [jQuery Validation Plugin v1.14.0](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation)

I know that we can check the form's field like:

```
  $( "#myform" ).validate({
    rules: {
      field: {
        required: true,
        url: true
      }
    }
  });
```

Is there a way to check string variable by this plugin and get `true` or `false` something like:

> var url = 'http://example.com'
>
> var isValidUrl = url.checkUrl() //

Comment: [AddMethod](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/241145/jquery-validate-plugin-how-to-create-a-simple-custom-rule)

Comment: Please review the documentation:  [you can attach `.valid()` to the form or an individual field to trigger a test and get a boolean](http://jqueryvalidation.org/valid)

Comment: Thank you for your comments.