# Add a Function Callback to Rules Validation Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I have this in my validation rules, it's working on,

```
'my_field': {
    required: true,
    number: false,
 }
```

But when I tried to do this,

```
'my_field': {
    required: true,
    number: function(){
      return false
    },
}
```

This always set my number to true, Why not false?

What did I do wrong?

Comment: I think you need to add the method, then you can call it. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/241202/1888402

Comment: Finally end up using addionalMethod. Thx.