# Unable to call exactlength property in validate.js

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am trying to validate my html file using `jquery.validate.js`. I need to verify the length of `mobileno` field which should be of 10 characters. Here is my code:

```
<!-- mobile number goes here. -->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="mobileno" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Mobile No.</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mobileno" name="mobileno" placeholder="Mobile No (10 digits)" required autofocus>
                    </div>
                    <span id="mobileno_error"></span>
                </div>
```

The js file  corresponding to it is:

```
 $("#register_form").validate({
        // Specify the validation rules
        rules: {
            name: "required",
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            mobileno: {
                required: true,
                exactlength: 10
            },
            password: {
              required: true,
              minlength: 6
          },
          confirm_password:{
            required: true,
            equalTo: '#password'
        }
    },

        // Specify the validation error messages
        messages: {
            name:"Please enter your name.",
            email: {
                required: 'Email address is required',
                email: 'Please enter a valid email address',
            },
            mobileno: {
                required: 'Mobile number is required',
                exactlength: 'The mobile number should be of 10 characters.',
            },
            password: {
                required: 'Password is required',
                minlength: 'The password should be of minimum 6 characters.',
            },
            confirm_password: {
                required: 'Confirm password is required',
                equalTo: 'The confirm password should match password.',
            }

        },
```

While leaving the `mobileno` field I am getting issue like:

> jquery.validate.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call'
>   of undefined.  Exception occurred when checking element mobileno,
>   check the 'exactlength' method.

I don't know what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *"I don't know what am I doing wrong?"*

The error is telling you exactly what you're doing wrong...

> Cannot read property 'call' of **undefined** ... check the **'exactlength'** method.

**[There is no such jQuery Validate rule called `exactlength`](https://jqueryvalidation.org/?s=exactlength)**.  You cannot just make up new rules by writing its word within the `rules` object.

To force a field to be exactly X characters in length, you'd use the `minlength` and `maxlength` rules together and set them both to X.

```
mobileno: {
    required: true,
    minlength: 10,
    maxlength: 10
},
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/jmhjwf70/**

Otherwise, there is a `phoneUS` rule within [the `additional-methods.js` file](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.15.0/additional-methods.js) you can use to validate any US phone number.   Also see `mobileUK`, `phoneUK`, `phonesUK`, and `phoneNL` for additional phone number rules.

If that's not satisfactory, then you could write your own rule using [the `.addMethod()` method](https://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/).

Comment: thank you very much for the help. can you guide me towards the implementation of the `addMethod()`?

Comment: @learner, you will have to try it and post a new question if you have any troubles.  However, you should see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/241145/594235) before doing that or it might get closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @learner, another tip: open the `additional-methods.js` file and examine how those rules are constructed.  They all use the `.addMethod()` method, so you can simply copy one and tweak it.

Comment: so basically additional-methods.js file is nothing but an extension to the existing validation file?

Comment: @learner, it's just a collection of more rules... you can include the whole thing, or just copy out what you need.  There are five phone number rules in there; surely one will get you close.

Answer (score 1):

```
rangelength: [10, 10]
```

This is the function for field to be exactly X characters in length. You have to add [additional-method.js](https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.15.0/additional-methods.js) otherwise it doesn't support