# How to check if a validation rule exists on an element in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I need to add a custom validation on datepicker just like we add custom validations by adding rules in javascript like the one here - [jQuery Validate Plugin - How to create a simple custom rule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/241145/jquery-validate-plugin-how-to-create-a-simple-custom-rule)

But before adding one more custom validator on same element I need to verify if another rule/validator method exists.

How can I check that? I know I can get all rules like -

```
var rules = $(element).rules();
```

Comment: Please provide some code

Comment: I need to add and remove rules like - $(element).rules("remove", "date"); Before adding or removing, I need to check if a validator rule is added like we have a greaterthandate validator. How do I fetch that from the list of rules which I have like - var rules = $(element).rules();

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rules is a dictionary type which can be fetched like below -

```
function findProperty(obj, key) {
    if (typeof obj === "object") {
        if (key in obj) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

var rules = $(element).rules();
if (rules) {
    var isGreater = findProperty(rules, 'greaterthandate');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After initialising the validate plugin, all the elements which have rules defined will return an object when you call `rules()` on it. This object contains the rule definitions, which you can check, something like this:

```js
$('form').validate()

var fooRequired = $('#foo').rules().required || false;
var barRequired = $('#bar').rules().required || false;

console.log('foo required? ' + fooRequired);
console.log('bar required? ' + barRequired)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>

<form>
  <input type="text" name="foo" id="foo" data-rule-required="true" />
  <input type="text" name="bar" id="bar" />
  <button type="submit">Go</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I need to add and remove rules like -                 $(element).rules("remove", "date");
Before adding or removing, I need to check if a validator rule is added like we have a greaterthandate validator. How do I fetch that from the list of rules which I have like - var rules = $(element).rules();