# How to validate filename in jQuery-Validation-Engine?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validation-engine

How to validate a filename in jQuery-Validation-Engine with no special characters allowed except for underscore (`_`)?

I tried these regex: `/^[a-zA-Z\d._]*$/` and `/^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$/` but no luck. The regex are valid based on https://regexr.com/

Here's my sample:

```js
"validFileName": {
  "regex": /^[a-zA-Z\d._]*$/,
  "alertText": "* Invalid filename"
},
```

Input tag:

```
<input type="file" name="attachment" id="attachment" class="validate[required, custom[validFileName]]"/>
```

Comment: Maybe this will work `/^[a-zA-Z_]+$/`

Comment: `.` means any character - so you've said: a to z upper/lower, any number or any other character

Comment: How are you adding `validFileName` and how are you using it?

Comment: Please see my updates how I used it on input type.

Comment: @Carsten Løvbo Andersen, based on your regex it will accept text only with underscore. tried it already still no luck

Comment: @freedomn-m, yes correct with the underscore characters.

Comment: Other than simply removing the `.` of the one that doesn't work or simply adding `\d` to @CarstenLøvboAndersen 's option - why do you think that your *other* option doesn't work?  `/^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$/`?  This follows your stated requirement of "no special characters except for underscore".  https://jsfiddle.net/s9ejv7bm/

Comment: I already did sir, but still no luck. Here's the updated code. https://jsfiddle.net/zsqakvhw/ changed to input type to file.

Comment: Right, so your *actual issue* is that the validation plugin doesn't work with `type=file` **regardless of the regex used**

Comment: Yes sir you're correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it. I'll post it here in-case someone need it. I used the call function:

**html:**

```
<input class="validate[required, funcCall[validFilename]]" type="file" name="attachment" id="attachment" />
```

**script:**

```
function validFilename(field, rules, i, options) {
    var uploadedFile = $(field);
    
    if (uploadedFile) {
    var extensions = rules[i + 1];               
    var mimeFilter = new RegExp(extensions);
    var file = document.getElementById('attachment').files[0].name;
    var pattern = new RegExp(/^[a-zA-Z0-9_.]+$/);
    
         if (!pattern.test( file ) ) {
              return '"' + file +  '" filename is invalid. No special character allowed.';
         }
        
    }

}
```

here's my working code: https://jsfiddle.net/26jkLhr9/

I know it is not the best answer but it worked! If you have a better and clean idea you are welcome to add it here.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this regex pattern- `([a-zA-Z\d._])\w+`

And change the class in input element as below-

`class="validate[required,custom[email]] text-input"`

Also have look at this for reference to create custom rule- [How to create simple custom rule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/241145/jquery-validate-plugin-how-to-create-a-simple-custom-rule)

Comment: The issue isn't the regex (and yours *still* as the `.` to allow any character) - it's that jquery-validation-engine doesn't work with `type='file'`

Comment: I got the idea of getting the filename by using javascript code (e.target.files[0].name) only then reinvent it to jquery-validation-engine, would it possible. but I don't know how to apply in on script.

Comment: By the way @praveen your answer is for jQuery Validate Plugin. But thanks for the headsup.