# JQuery Validate: custom rule triggering on specific events

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I would like to add a custom rule to jQuery Validate that allows me to do a check and some specific actions according to the event triggering it.
For example for an email, after the 1st submit of the form (blocked by Validate):

- if the event is a submit:

  - check if the email already exists (ajax call)
  - if the email domain "looks like" a known domain name: suggest it (popup, or blocking the form validation once)
- if its a keyup:

  - if the email domain "looks like" a known domain name: do some passive suggestions
  - if there are some common misstypings, suggest the correct spelling

The field I'm targeting already has some other rules that will trigger on all default trigger events of jQuery Validate (after submission: keyup, focusout etc.) and I want to keep it this way.
(for the email example: run an email regex)

For this reason, **I would like to use the event triggering the rule check to determine my custom rule's actions**.

I wanted first to pass the event through the rules params but couldn't figure out where to get it from.

My current solution for this is as follows:

set the event on some variable when it's caught by validate and keep the default validation going

```js
var validationEvent;

$('#myForm').submit(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
    validationEvent = event;
}).validate({
    onkeyup: function(element, event) {
        validationEvent = event;
        $(element).valid();
    },
    rules: {
        email: {
            required: true,
            myCustomFunction: true,
            email: true
        }
    }
});
```

My custom function would then look like this:

```js
$.validator.addMethod("myCustomFunction", function(value, element, params) {
    if (validationEvent == undefined) {
        return true;
    }

    if (validationEvent.type == "submit") {
        // do something
    }

    if (validationEvent.type == "keyup") {
        // do something else
    }
});
```

This feels bad to do (and is probably bad) and i'd like to make it good.

my best guess would be to somehow pass the event through the rules params like this:

```js
$('#myForm').validate({
    rules: {
        email: {
            myCustomFunction: event
        }
    }
});

$.validator.addMethod("myCustomFunction", function(value, element, params) {
    if (params.type == "submit") {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Is there a possibility to do it like this, or through another way?

Comment: Perhaps some other questions answers might help get you on you way example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/241202/125981 - there are many similar examples

Comment: Please fix your description to describe ***why*** you need to validate again after validation was completed.  Explain what you're trying to achieve through all this?

Comment: The `onsubmit` option can only be a boolean value, not a function, as per documentation.  Please see: https://jqueryvalidation.org   Also `$(element).valid()` is another call to validate the element, and it makes no sense here because that's what it's already doing.

Comment: *"if the event is a submit: let it go to other rules, if its a keyup: do some regex validations and suggest some options"*  - not making any sense and need more explanation.  Everything for a single field needs to be handled by its rules.  Rules are not normally different based on the type of triggering method.  This does not sound like a normal GUI experience.

Comment: @Sparky I added some examples and fixed the `onsubmit`. The `valid()` function is needed to trigger the validation after giving some custom instructions through the `onkeyup` (here) callback. My goal here might not be ideal in design but that isn't the problem to solve here, I could do some functions outside of the lib to create this behavior but i'd prefer to use the same logic as other validations. In the end, my goal is to do some validations according to the event and i'd like to find the best way to do it.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss I looked through a lot of similar questions already and couldn't find any which answered my question sadly. I'm still searching for it on the side though.

Comment: There is already a method called `remote` designed exactly for the scenario you describe - like checking if a username already exists.  No need to mingle around with custom event triggers and re-invention of the wheel.

Comment: *"I looked through a lot of similar questions already and couldn't find any which answered my question sadly."* - You should ask yourself "why" you cannot find a similar question.  There are over 6,000 questions about this plugin and trying to force it to do certain rules that are dependent on triggering events is not normal at all.

Comment: You would never be needing a custom `.submit()` handler function with this plugin.... keep looking at other example code and questions.  This plugin blocks and handles the submit event internally and automatically.  Your function is redundant and/or will break the expected behavior of the form or plugin.

Comment: Not 100% clear on your requirement but you can also trigger a validation on elements for example `$("#myform").validate().element("#myid");` or check a conditional `if ($('#myid').valid()){`   OR perhaps on an event `$('#myForm input.myclass[type=textbox][name=yourtxbboxName]').on('change'
 function(e){
  $("#myForm").valid();
}
)`